# Capturing Cross-Origin iframe Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, youtube

I have a website at domain A that contains an iframe used to show a video, which is hosted on YouTube.  On the iframe load event, I am attempting to register for the keyup event in the iframe so I can close the video when a client presses the escape key.  Here is an example of my code:

```
$(myIFrame).bind('load', function() {
    $(myIFrame.contentWindow.document).keyup(function(event) {
        console.log(event.keyCode);
    });
    alert('Event Registered');
});
```

I am getting the following exceptions:

Firefox: `Error: Permission denied to access property "document"`
Chrome: `Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "A" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

Is there any way to register for events in a cross-origin iframe?

Comment: Can you change source code of page from domain B?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have absolutely no control over domain B.  B is https://www.youtube-nocookie.com.

Comment: So you cannot using javascript for security reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) is preventing you from doing this.

An origin consists of a scheme, port, protocol and domain. If these match, then JavaScript can be used to register events or to manipulate the DOM.

If your site is `http://example.com` and the video is on `http://example.org` then cross domain scripting will not be possible because the domains do not match.

It is possible for different origins to communicate, however they both need to opt into this functionality. [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) is one such JavaScript function. However as you have no control of the origin running the video it cannot help you here.

On solution for you may be to display the video inline on your page. This should enable you to capture events.

Comment: I guess that I was hoping that since both endpoints utilize SSL, that there was a way to override the same origin policy.  YouTube does support a [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), but the events exposed by that API are higher level than keyup.