# Accessing a parent object from an iframe (cross-origin)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I need to run an iframe on websites which will load in JavaScript for them to allow them to use a feature use on their webpage.

The iframe needs to be able to access the parent object so it can show and hide various things on the page.

Main html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var SomeApi = {};
    SomeApi.clickMe = function() {
        //some event
    }
</script>
```

Iframe:

```
<a href='#' onclick='parent.SomeApi.clickMe();return false;'>Click me</a>
```

I get the error:

`SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "SomeApi" on cross-origin object`

The iframe URL I am sending is using node.js express with the following headers:

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

What headers or configuration do I need to do so that I don't get the cross-origin object error and I can access the parent object?

The code will always be run on a different domain to the iframe.

Comment: Those headers only work on xhr it does nothing for iframe. I suggest you search cross orgin iframe communication. FYI it involves hacks because Cross origin iframes are not supposed to be able to communicate.

Comment: You have to use postMessage for the two to communicate:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30503292/877610

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments by Darkrum the issue wasn't with the headers as that's for XHR. I figured out the solution I required by doing a little workaround.

IFRAME html:

```
<iframe id='iframe-id' src='about:blank'></iframe>
```

I loaded the contents of the iframe using `ajax` like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.exampledomain.com",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#iframe-id").contents().find('body').html(data);
    }
});
```

This allowed me to access the parent objects I required

```
<a href='#' onclick='parent.SomeApi.clickMe();return false;'>Click me</a>
```

I had to do this method as I required the contents to be in an iframe.